# Proof of the finiteness of integral (in option pricing)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, finance

I would like to ask for help with proving the finiteness of the following double integral.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\alpha+k}\int_{k+\zeta}^{\infty} (e^{-\zeta+x}-e^k)f(x)\  \mbox{d}x\  \mbox{d}k,$$

where $\alpha>0$, $\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is probability density function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\zeta+x}f(x) \mbox{d}x<\infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the option you are pricing? I believe you need more conditions such as that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2x} f(x) < \infty$.

Comment: I try to price call option.  I think sufficient condition is that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(\alpha+1)x}f(x) < \infty $